# How to add conversational memory to pandas toolkit agent?

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

I want to add a `ConversationBufferMemory` to `pandas_dataframe_agent` but so far I was unsuccessful.

- I have tried adding the memory via construcor: `create_pandas_dataframe_agent(llm, df, verbose=True, memory=memory)` which didn't break the code but didn't resulted in the agent to remember my previous questions.
- Also I have tried to add memory into the agent via this pieace of code: `pd_agent.agent.llm_chain.memory = memory`. Which resulted in `ValueError: One input key expected got ['input', 'agent_scratchpad']`

This is my code so far (which doesn't work):

```
llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model_name="gpt-4-0613")

memory = ConversationBufferMemory()

pd_agent = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(llm, df, verbose=True, memory=memory)
#pd_agent.agent.llm_chain.memory = memory #Or if I use this approach the code breaks when calling the .run() methods

pd_agent.run("Look into the data in step 12. Are there any weird patterns? What can we say about this part of the dataset.")
pd_agent.run("What was my previouse question?") #Agent doesn't rember
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the Jakub's answer, we can skip the manual step of `prompt.py` file modification by passing the `prefix` parameter to the `create_pandas_dataframe_agent` function.

```
PREFIX = """
You are working with a pandas dataframe in Python. The name of the dataframe is `df`.
You should use the tools below to answer the question posed of you:

Summary of the whole conversation:
{chat_history_summary}

Last few messages between you and user:
{chat_history_buffer}

Entities that the conversation is about:
{chat_history_KG}
"""

pd_agent = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(
    llm_code, 
    df,
    prefix=PREFIX, 
    verbose=True, 
    agent_executor_kwargs={"memory": memory},
    input_variables=['df_head', 'input', 'agent_scratchpad', 'chat_history_buffer', 'chat_history_summary', 'chat_history_KG']
)
```

Comment: Very nice! +1 from me

Answer (score 1):

In the version `0.0.202` the only way I found out to add memory into pandas_agent is like this (you also need to change the `prompt.py` file - how-to is written below the code):

```
We want to create two diffrent models - one for generating code and the second one for the context
llm_code = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model_name="gpt-4-0613") #gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613
llm_context = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.5, model_name="gpt-4") #gpt-3.5-turbo

chat_history_buffer = ConversationBufferWindowMemory(
    k=5,
    memory_key="chat_history_buffer",
    input_key="input"
    )

chat_history_summary = ConversationSummaryMemory(
    llm=llm_context, 
    memory_key="chat_history_summary",
    input_key="input"
    )

chat_history_KG = ConversationKGMemory(
    llm=llm_context, 
    memory_key="chat_history_KG",
    input_key="input",
    )

memory = CombinedMemory(memories=[chat_history_buffer, chat_history_summary, chat_history_KG])

pd_agent = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(
    llm_code, 
    df, 
    verbose=True, 
    agent_executor_kwargs={"memory": memory},
    input_variables=['df_head', 'input', 'agent_scratchpad', 'chat_history_buffer', 'chat_history_summary', 'chat_history_KG']
    )
```

First you specify for each memory type you want to use a `memory_key`. This `memory_key` needs to be passed into `input_variables`.

You also need to pass the memory object into the pandas_agent like this:

```
agent_executor_kwargs={"memory": memory}
```

### VERY IMPORTANT!!!

You ***need*** to change the `prompt.py` file located in `../langchain/agents/agent_toolkits/pandas/prompt.py` to take into account the new memory you added.

The only thing you need to change is `PREFIX`. This is the change that worked for me:

```
PREFIX = """
You are working with a pandas dataframe in Python. The name of the dataframe is `df`.
You should use the tools below to answer the question posed of you:

Summary of the whole conversation:
{chat_history_summary}

Last few messages between you and user:
{chat_history_buffer}

Entities that the conversation is about:
{chat_history_KG}
"""
```

Comment: When I try to run this using the following command:
pd_agent.run('the shape of the dataset?')
I get this error:
ValueError: A single string input was passed in.

I tried

pd_agent.run({'df_head':df.head(), 'input':'get the number of nulls in each column and print it', 'agent_scratchpad':"", 'chat_history_buffer':chat_history_buffer, 'chat_history_summary':chat_history_summary,'chat_history_KG':chat_history_KG})
which seems to work but doesn't keep a memory of the previous output.

Comment: You need to change the `prompt.py` file - it seems like you didn't add the memory keys into the prompt.

Comment: I did according to the instructions. There are multiple prompt.py files. I added it to one of them. Dont know if that was the right one.

Comment: In my answer I also specified the path to the file - there should only be one.
Also did you use all memory types? Or just one?

Comment: What is the catch behind adding 2 different models?

Comment: Not working. Agent does not remember